# how to parse the answer (array) you get in the API (GET) query in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm querying get into flutter, and I'm getting back  array (one object in the array). I want to parse this answer and assign the data from the array object to the variable. But I can't do it. Here is my request:

```html
  Future<Null>   example(
      String? task_id
      ) async {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback =
    ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    final String url = urlVar "?id="+  '$task_id';

    final request = await client
        .getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));


    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

    var responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

    Map jsonResponse = json.decode(responseBody);

    print(jsonResponse);


  }
```

My answer json

```html
[
  {
    "id": "d290111e-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
    "name": "Parse example",
   }
]
```

I want to parse this answer and assign it to my variables. I did it like when the answer was in the object, I did it like this. But with array  not, I will be grateful for help)

```html
    var responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

    Map jsonResponse = json.decode(responseBody);

    print(jsonResponse);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      global.taskId = jsonResponse['id'] ;
      global.taskName = jsonResponse['name'];

    }
```

Comment: Try to re-check what json.decode result, is it `Map` or `List`

Comment: @cahyo my json   [
      {
        "id": "d290111e-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
        "name": "Parse example",
       }
    ]

Comment: This may have already been answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001839/how-to-convert-response-json-to-object-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  global.taskId = jsonResponse[0]['id'] ;
  global.taskName = jsonResponse[0]['name'];

}
```